# Can I make Gson.fromJson() use String.intern or use a StringPool for heavily used Strings

Tags: java, json, gson, string-interning

I am using Gson to deserialize a large number of JSON documents and performance analysis shows that garbage collection is straining to keep up and suspension time is very high due to that. I suspect that Gson creates a large number of strings for all the elements in the JSON document and after processing these are freed up again quickly.

I googled and found [some discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gson/MVUagkzIUSk) that did not lead anywhere.

I agree that it is not useful to intern all Strings, usually interning can be useful if you specify which things should be interned, e.g. keys for maps in JSON are usually a good bet.

Is there a way to tell Gson which strings to intern, e.g. via a specialized serializer? Or is there a way to have a StringPool for things like map-keys to avoid having to allocate these items on the heap all the time.

Comment: Do you have custom deserializers? If yes, are you using `JsonDeserializer` or `TypeAdapter`? Have you used a profiler to see where exactly these strings are being created?

Comment: Always use a profiler, don't suspect things. First, it is fun to use a profiler. Second, you may find other problems or cool stuff.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Propably not a full solution, but I found `addDeserializationExclusionStrategy()` which allows to decide about creating fields before they are actually deserialized, this can also help in reducing the overhead incurred by the JSON parsing:

```
        new GsonBuilder().addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                return false;
            }
        }).
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?